# How to Count the number of chart prints in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to track the number of times the 'Print Chart' option is clicked from the Highcharts context menu on a chart.

There is no mention of the word 'print' in the highcharts.js file and the only reference to printing in the highcharts api documentation is the `chart.print()` [function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.print%28%29), but the context menu doesn't print via this method (I setup a console.log to see if `chart.print()` gets called from the context menu, and it doesn't; so that function is just for programatically calling a print).

So basically I need to hook into the way highcharts prints so I can count the function calls.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Print function is available in exporting.js file.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.print()

Comment: Thanks but that's the same function I linked in my question. ;)